# Mongoid DateTime: What is the right date?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid to store DateTime. But now i'm confusing with the real date.
In mongodb , the date is stored as:

```
{"2013-01-14T12:50:00.000Z"}
```

But when i print that value, it says:

```
2013-01-14T19:50:00+07:00
```

I don't really understand whether those Date formats are the same, and which one is "right" in my current timezone ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Date is stored in GMT, when "printed", it is displayed in your local timezone (GMT+7?)

Comment: Oh, when i tested in IRB with mongo ruby driver, i got the value is
    2013-01-15 12:50:00 UTC

Do you know how to make GMT-7, in fact the result from mongoid go ahead 7 hours in comparison with my right value.

Comment: I need my local timezone (GMT+7), but by default, Mongoid stores my datetime as UTC ? Do you know how to configure Mongoid to use my local timezone ?

Comment: As stated in docs, Mongo stores all dates in UTC - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date

Answer (score 1):

The default Ruby date object should be able to handle offsets in time:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

Whereby some way down the page it even talks about how to start manipulating it I believe:

> An optional argument the offset indicates the difference between the local time and UTC.

I do believe that mongoid is already converting the time for you as can be seen by the `T` value within the iso date being 7 hours ahead:

```
2013-01-14T19:50:00+07:00
```

Merely if you were to print the date and/or time instead of the full output with the offset included I have no doubt you will get the real date.

I believe mongoid most likely prints the offset even when it is applied because that offset IS there (since the time is off-setted by 7 hours from UTC) it is just not applied further.